# Where to store the ASP.NET Forms Authentication cookie in an objective-c iPhone/iPad application?

Tags: objective-c, asp.net-mvc

I am writing an iPhone app (not browser) that will communicate w/ an ASP.NET MVC application on the server which uses forms authentication. After obtaining the authentication cookie from the user login screen where should I store the authentication cookie?

Is NSHTTPCookieStorage the best place?

Then I am considering a class method

```
+ (NSString) getAuthCookie;
```

that can be used throughout the app to retrieve the authorization cookie so it can be sent w/ URL requests.

Any references and insights into the best approach to this area appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to save password or things alike, I think you should use KeyChain service in iOS.

here is an simple example:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html

keychain service  concept https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: I understand the keychain concept and implementation. However, how do I store an object like HTTPCookie in it? Most of the data types seem to be strings, dates, etc.